# Automation for ADF V2 Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-automation

I need help with implementation for below requirement:

There is one ADF pipeline that runs every two hours (with Tumbling window trigger), now i need to create one more pipeline that will be used for performing maintenance job . This pipeline is scheduled to run once a month (with schedule trigger). Here is the requirement that i'm trying to implement:

1. Now before running the second pipeline i need to make sure the first pipeline is not running (basically get the status and if its running wait for its completion) and then disable the trigger associated with it.
2. Run the second pipeline and after its completion , enable the trigger that is associated with first pipeline

Please let me know if this can be achieved within ADF or some kind of custom scripting needed to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

First, your idea is achievable.

Second, if you want to use built-in feature in Azure Datafactory, then there is no way.

Basically, you need to use Azure function (simple httptrigger, don't give any input, then you can hit and execute it directly) to achieve your requirement that ADF can't do. From your description, the executing of these two pipelines are mutually exclusive, so you can use sdk to check to status of another pipeline in Azure function. If another pipeline is running, then wait a few seconds then re-check the status of another pipeline. (In short, put the main logic and code in the Azure function.)

Simple Azure function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp

Use SDK to monitor:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically#net

(The link I give is C#, you can choose other supported language.)

[image]

Comment: can i use powershell and execute the same with Azure Automation run book.? Which one will ne more cost effective Azure Function/ Azure Automation run book.. provided if i go through dedicated App Service plan for Azure Function